# Arrays (C++): why use pointers over direct manipulation?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I understand pointers really well and I understand a lot of their uses. However, I have never figured out the use of pointers in arrays. I know how to do it, but I don't understand why use this over direct manipulation of the array. I just wanna know something I can only do using pointers in arrays. Thanks.

Comment: how about dynamically allocating multidimensional arrays?

Comment: What exactly is "direct manipulation"?

Comment: Direct manipulation: array[0] = 5

Comment: The situation isn't really any different than it is for non-array objects. Why have pointers when you can access objects directly, for example `int a; a = 5;`? Because for various purposes you want a level of indirection, a value that can refer to an object (or an element of an array). As it happens, though, `array[0]` is *by definition* `*(array + 0)`, so what you call direct manipulation is defined in terms of pointers.

Answer (score 6):

Consider:

```
struct Match {
    int scores[30];
    char names[30][64];
    int ages[30];
    char description[1024];
};
```

This structure is 3184 bytes long.

```
Match matches[16];
```

If I decide that matches[0] and matches[1] need to be swapped, swapping the two involves the following work to be done (this is how std::swap is implemented):

```
Match temp; // prepare 3184 bytes on the stack.
temp = matches[0]; // copy 3184 bytes
matches[0] = matches[1]; // copy 3184 bytes
matches[1] = temp; // copy 3184 bytes
```

Thats a lot of cpu cycles copying/moving data.

If I used pointers:

```
Match* matches[16];
for (size_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    mathces[i] = new Match;
}
```

all std::swap has to do is swap two pointers:

```
Match* temp = matches[0]; // 4 or 8 bytes
matches[0] = matches[1]; // 4 or 8 bytes
matches[1] = temp; // 4 or 8 bytes
```

Much cleaner, and when optimized, this can probably be done in registers for extreme performance.

Another advantage of this is memory savings. I can have an array of 1,000,000 Match pointers, that occupies 4Mb or 8Mb (depending on 32/64 bits) many of which can be `nullptr`. I only need pointers to entries that are currently useful.

An array of 1,000,000 Match objects requires 3Gbs of ram.

Conversely, if all 1,000,000 pointers have to point to a unique Match object instance, then you'd have ~3Gb of objects plus ~1Mb of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You see, an array is different from an object. The array itself is allocating memory as a block. The array then contents the pointers to the values. This means, you could do array1 = array2. The values itselves are not copied, only the addresses.

Why an array is a pointer is because of memory management, it would be too easy to duplicate arrays. Arrays doesn't work like objects.

When you access index 1 in array, you asked the array: Tell me the value at the adress stored at index 1 of this array.

While I'm not the best in C++ especially pointers, I'm pretty sure this is how it works.